# Uso de EXISTS en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo un problema para crear un procedimiento almacenado que inserte información de productos en una tabla el cual debe verificar si el producto ya existe, si es así que muestre un mensaje, si no que inserte los datos.

```
CREATE OR REPlACE PROCEDURE sp_InsertarProducto (idProd IN VARCHAR2, descrip IN VARCHAR2, exis IN NUMBER)
as
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('ESTE PRODUCTO YA HA SIDO INGRESADO')
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE IdProducto = idProd);


  INSERT INTO Productos (IdProducto, Descripcion, Existencia)
  VALUES(idProd, descrip, exis)
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE IdProducto = idProd);
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Observación

La forma en como lo planteas no es la forma natural en como se harían este tipo de cosas, ya que si trabaja en un equipo de desarrollo y alguien planea hacer algo que incluya intenta realizar una inserción de determinado producto a tu tabla y decide no usar tu procedimiento, te veras en un problema.

### Solución

La mejor manera de realizar esto, teniendo en cuenta que la única condición que colocas es que no exista ya, es crear un indice único a la columna `IdProducto` y posteriormente validar la inserción en tu procedimiento con una excepción de tipo violación de indice de la siguiente forma:

```sql
CREATE OR REPlACE PROCEDURE sp_InsertarProducto (
  idProd  IN VARCHAR2
, descrip IN VARCHAR2
, exis    IN NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Productos (IdProducto, Descripcion, Existencia)
  VALUES(idProd, descrip, exis);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('ESTE PRODUCTO YA HA SIDO INGRESADO');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

La condicion WHERE EXISTS se usa en las consultas SQL, no en los procedures de la forma en la que la estas usando. Prueba a usar las condiciones IF. Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE OR REPlACE PROCEDURE sp_InsertarProducto (idProd IN VARCHAR2, descrip IN VARCHAR2, exis IN NUMBER)
as
begin
  if (select count(*) FROM Productos WHERE IdProducto = idProd) >= 1 then
  dbms_output.put_line('ESTE PRODUCTO YA HA SIDO INGRESADO');
  else
  INSERT INTO Productos (IdProducto, Descripcion, Existencia)
  VALUES(idProd, descrip, exis);
  end if;
end;
```